# Using BBBadgeBarButtonItem it was working fine in swift 1.2, after shifting to 2.0 it is not working proper

Tags: swift, badge

Hey hi I am currently working on swift 2.0 `BadgeBarButtonItem` was working fine in swift 1.2 but in 2.0 when `ViewController` loads first time it shows square and then on second time it appears circle.

I am calling following method from controllers viewDidLoad()

```
 func createBadgeButton(customButton: UIButton)  -> BBBadgeBarButtonItem {

    var barButton: BBBadgeBarButtonItem?

    customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "nav_cart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    barButton = BBBadgeBarButtonItem(customView: customButton)

    var cartBadgeNumber: Int = 12

    barButton!.badgeValue = String(cartBadgeNumber)
    barButton!.badgeOriginX = 22
    barButton!.badgeOriginY = -7
    barButton!.badgeFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 11)
    barButton!.badgeMinSize = 6.0
    barButton!.badgeBGColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    barButton!.badgeTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    barButton?.shouldAnimateBadge = true
    barButton!.shouldHideBadgeAtZero = true

    return barButton!

}
```

Comment: Can you please put some code, when you are allocating?

Comment: Can you please call this method to viewDidAppear?

Comment: By doing that way it appears same for first time. But second time returing back to controller show first circle and then square again.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to handle it, actually what we need to do is again update the value to self. So, I have edited the library of `BadgeBarButtonItem` and added the below line to setBadgeValue() function. It worked for me.

```
[self updateBadgeFrame];
```